# MS Office Apps not working after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-office, crash

After upgrading to Windows 10, MS Office Apps (e.g. Excel, Word, etc) crash.

The error message refers to `excel.exe`, which seems to be missing completely on my local setup.

I tried copying the `excel.bak.exe` file and renaming it, but get the same error. Suggestions?

Comment: What version of Office are you using?  Have you uninstall it then reinstall that version?  If you have not tried that you should

Answer (score 0):

Please try to repair your installation of Office.

1. open your **control panel** by pressing Win+X and then clicking Control pannel
2. click on **Uninstall a program**
3. on the following window click again **uninstall a program**
4. search for your **Microsoft Office entry**
5. **right-click** that entry and select **change**
6. now your choice depends on your office version... Office 365 gives me two options: quick repair and online repair. Choose what ever suits you - if Office isn't working at all I would go for the big repair (which would be the online repair)

Comment: I had a strange problem with Excel crashing whenever I saved a workbook that contained VBA code. I went the repair install route, and chose the smaller option. It was all I needed. So you might as well do the minimum that will fix it.